# Django ORM delete

Tags: django, postgresql

Ok so i have 2 models simplified

```
Class A:
    name  = charfield

Class B:
     name = charfield
     linked = foreignkey(A)
```

My question how I can delete **A.name** and **B.linked** but protecting **B.name** from being deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `ForeignKey.on_delete` argument (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)

You'll want to do

```
linked = models.ForeignKey(A, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: Also, please search the Django documentation before asking questions. In this case, it was logically in the `ForeignKey` section of the documentation.

Comment: searched it but i wasn't paying attention